# Rails: Can I use Template Pattern to inject executable code into controller and use rich subclassing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, controller

I've got a widget base class and 50 different kinds of child widget subclasses. Each child widget provides its own partial view. A Page object is defined with a configuration of 2 to 3 of these widgets, and calls a view__generator method that creates a single view erb file for that particular page by retrieving and compositing the partial views that are associated with each of the widgets.

For example, a Page about dolphins might include an Image widget and a radio button choice widget. the generator function creates a single view page. (Yes, I know that it sounds like I should just be using built in rails and html constructs, but there is a method to the madness).

My problem is that I can't figure out how to composite the data requirements into a single set of code that can be run by the controller prior to rendering the composited view.

For example, widget A might require a query of Foo.all while widget B might require a calculation of a form variable called "total_sum".

I've considered two approaches:
1) figure out how to take widget-specific blocks of code and execute them in the context of the base Page controller.

I tried using Procs but the Proc variables aren't available outside of the scope of the Proc. I know that I can write the code into the partial views, but I'd really rather avoid the mixing of concerns.

2) do the data queries and computation on the widget model, and pass the data back as a hash that can then be bound to an instance variable in the base class and made available to the composited view.

I'm pretty sure 2 is the preferred direction, but I'd be interested in guidance on best practices.

Comment: I think you should post some concrete code. It sounds like you're trying to do some DI in your controller and might be making it more complex than it needs to / should be. Why not just have two different widgets?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what I describe in choice 2. Each model can pull up any data it needs and serialize it into a hash that is always made available to the view.